# Modifying an angulardart material component

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components

I am working with angular_dart and angular_components (material).

I am trying to use a material-dropdown-select with long strings. However, the max width of the popup is limited to 448px, hard-coded. (see [source](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/lib/material_select/material_dropdown_select.dart#L493))

What would be the best way to edit / inherit / override that component, so that I can specify the width I want?

Thanks!

Comment: You could make a feature request to allow other values. Not sure if extending can work, but I guess it's worth a try.

Comment: Added a feature request: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/255

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

1) Add PopupSizeProviderDirective in the directives of the parent component
2) Use something like ....